# Type guard to check valid type

Tags: typescript

I have such code:

```
const languages = ["en", "de", "ar"] as const;

export type TranslationLanguage = (typeof languages)[number];
```

in these case the type of `TranslationLanguage = "en" | "de" | "ar"` everything is fine.
But how can I implement function that checks my type and gives true/false for example if string that passes is my `TranslationLanguage` type?

Pseudo code:

```
function checkAvailableLanguage(
  language: string
): language is TranslationLanguage {
   if (language typeof TranslationLanguage){
    return true
   else{
    return false
   }
}
```

Comment: `return languages.includes(language)`?

Comment: another issue in that case
function checkLanguage(language: string): language is TranslationLanguage {
  return languages.includes(language);
}
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"en" | "ru" | "ar"'
Because ive did const languages = ["en", "de", "ar"] as const;

Comment: So type assert it: https://tsplay.dev/WKvPom or https://tsplay.dev/wj802m

Comment: @jonrsharpe bless u, and all your family!)